# python circular dependency issue: unexpected error

Tags: python

I have some python files in a directory called 'circular_dependency':

import_file_1.py:

```
from circular_dependency.import_file_2 import *

def add_one(x):
    return x+1
```

import_file_2.py:

```
from circular_dependency.import_file_1 import *

def add_two(x):
    return add_one(add_one(x))
```

and finally main.py

```
from circular_dependency.import_file_1 import *
from circular_dependency.import_file_2 import *

x = 17
print(add_two(x))
```

running main.py results in the following error:

```
/Users/fabianwerner/anaconda3/envs/academy/bin/python /Users/fabianwerner/BI-X/academy/exercises/01_exMON_python/circular_dependency/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabianwerner/BI-X/academy/exercises/01_exMON_python/circular_dependency/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(add_two(x))
  File "/Users/fabianwerner/BI-X/academy/exercises/01_exMON_python/circular_dependency/import_file_2.py", line 4, in add_two
    return add_one(add_one(x))
NameError: name 'add_one' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As far as I have understood, python does not really cope well with circular (well, actually those are non-harmful) "circular" dependencies. So I would have expected an error where python complains about the fact that I have created a circular dependency.

--> Questions:

1. Why does python not complain about the circular dependency?
2. What does the error below mean? Why can't the function `add_two` in import_file_2.py find the function `add_one` from import_file_1.py althoug I have imported that function?

Thanks for clearing this up :-)

Comment: Why does python not complain about the circular dependency? it is a silent error. Annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the imports in `main.py` matters in this case.

Starting from `main.py`, you first import `import_file_1`. This causes contents of `import_file_1` to be loaded into the namespace. Now as part of the first line of `import_file_1.py`, you import `import_file_2`, which adds `add_two()` to the namespace.

Note that by now, `add_one()` is still undefined. When control goes back into `import_file_1`, `add_one()` finally gets added to the namespace. However, logically, this happens *after* the definition of `add_two()` which raises the error.

Switching the import lines in `main.py` to the following fixes the issue:

```py
from circular_dependency.import_file_2 import *
from circular_dependency.import_file_1 import *
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped me to understand it better :-)

Answer (score 1):

1 - No idea

2 - What happens is:

Python stores the imported modules in it's cache, namely sys.modules. When a lookup / import happens, it first looks at the cache and uses it if the module is already imported. So, basically you can do import mymodule a hundred times and it's only imported the first time, rest will just be dictionary lookups.

In a circular dependency scenario:

- file 1 imported
- file 2 immediately imported due to import in file 1
- file 1 immediately imported in file 2
- file 1 is already in sys.modules so no need to import, continue to file 2

There you have an empty shell of file 1 in sys.modules. Referencing a function in file 1 will end up in name error.

You could do this instead:

```
file 2

def add_two():
   from file1 import add_one
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look up the sys.modules mechanics.